# Java Calculating queue for two ArrayList or HashMap

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 classes: 1 for number of vehicles arriving at a
 certain time, and the second the actual planning with the number of
 vehicles allowed to pass. The input data looks like this :

`Vehicle Arriving` (looping on this list, because planning may miss some values)

```
01/01/2018 00:00:00 12
01/01/2018 00:10:00 10
01/01/2018 01:00:00 5
01/01/2018 01:10:00 10
```

`Planning` (Last planning based on Timestamp is the one to take)

```
01/01/2018 00:00:00 2
01/01/2018 00:10:00  4
01/01/2018 01:00:00 6
```

---

What I would like to achieve is to have another Class or hashmap with key date (or datetime) with the time, and the number of vehicles in the queue.

In our example :

```
01/01/2018 00:00:00 | 12-2=10
01/01/2018 00:10:00 | 10-4+10(previous) =16
01/01/2018 01:00:00 | 5-6+16
01/01/2018 01:10:00 | 10-6(last value if planning not found)+15
```

My class implementation

```
class Vehicle {
    private Date date;
    private int nbOfVehicleArriving;

    public Vehicle(Date date, int nbOfVehicleArriving) {
        this.date = date;
        this.nbOfVehicleArriving = nbOfVehicleArriving;
    }

    public int getNbOfVehicleArriving() {
        return nbOfVehicleArriving;
    }
}


class Planning {
    private Date date;
    private int nbOfallowedVehicles;

    public Planning(Date date, int nbOfallowedVehicles) {
        this.date = date;
        this.nbOfallowedVehicles = nbOfallowedVehicles;
    }

    public int getNbOfallowedVehicles() {
        return nbOfallowedVehicles;
    }
}

class Queue {
    private Date date;
    private int nbOfVehiclesInQueue;
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

My lame attempt :

```
 if (planningList != null && vehiclesList != null) {
            queues1 = new ArrayList<>();
            int j = 0;
            long count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < planningList.size() - 1; i++) {
                Date nextTime = planningList.get(i + 1).getTimestamp();
                Integer nbOfVehiclesAllowed = planningList.get(i).getNbOfallowedVehicles();
                while (j < vehiclesList.size() && vehiclesList.get(j).getTime() < nextTime.getTime()) {
                    count = Math.max(vehiclesList.get(j).nbOfVehicleArriving() - nbOfVehiclesAllowed + count, 0);
                    queues1.add(new Queue(vehiclesList.get(j).getDate(), count));
                    j++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: 1) It looks like you've missed off the bottom of your Queue class 2) Do not use `java.util.Date`. Use `java.time.LocalDateTime`

Comment: @user7 edited with my lame attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class Queue has data and noOfVehiclesInQueue as member variables.

```
  class Vehicle {
        private Date date;
        private int nbOfVehicleArriving;

        public Vehicle(Date date, int nbOfVehicleArriving) {
            this.date = date;
            this.nbOfVehicleArriving = nbOfVehicleArriving;
        }

        public int getNbOfVehicleArriving() {
            return nbOfVehicleArriving;
        }

        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }       

    }


    class Planning {
        private Date date;
        private int nbOfallowedVehicles;

        public Planning(Date date, int nbOfallowedVehicles) {
            this.date = date;
            this.nbOfallowedVehicles = nbOfallowedVehicles;
        }

        public int getNbOfallowedVehicles() {
            return nbOfallowedVehicles;
        }
    }


    class Queue {
        private Date date;
        private int noOfVehiclesInQueue;

        public Queue(Date date, int noOfVehiclesInQueue) {
            this.date = date;
            this.noOfVehiclesInQueue = noOfVehiclesInQueue;
        }

        public int getNoOfVehiclesInQueue() {
            return noOfVehiclesInQueue;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Queue [date=" + date + ", noOfVehiclesInQueue=" + noOfVehiclesInQueue + "]";
        }           

    }


    public class Demo {         

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<Vehicle> veh=new ArrayList<>();
            List<Planning> plan=new ArrayList<>();
            List<Queue> queue=new ArrayList<>();

            veh.add(new Vehicle(new Date("01/01/2018 00:00:00"), 12));
            veh.add(new Vehicle(new Date("01/01/2018 00:10:00"), 10));
            veh.add(new Vehicle(new Date("01/01/2018 01:00:00"), 5));
            veh.add(new Vehicle(new Date("01/01/2018 01:10:00"), 10));

            plan.add(new Planning(new Date("01/01/2018 00:00:00"), 2));
            plan.add(new Planning(new Date("01/01/2018 00:10:00"), 4));
            plan.add(new Planning(new Date("01/01/2018 01:00:00"), 6));

            for(int i=0;i<veh.size();i++) {

                int vehicleinpreviousqueue=(i!=0)?queue.get(i-1).getNoOfVehiclesInQueue():0;
                int vehiclearrving=veh.get(i).getNbOfVehicleArriving();
                int vehicleallowed=(i<veh.size()-1)?plan.get(i).getNbOfallowedVehicles():plan.get(i-1).getNbOfallowedVehicles();
                int vehicleinqueue=((vehicleinpreviousqueue+vehiclearrving-vehicleallowed)>0)?(vehicleinpreviousqueue+vehiclearrving-vehicleallowed):0;     


                queue.add(new Queue(veh.get(i).getDate(), vehicleinqueue));

            }

          for(Queue q:queue) System.out.println(q.toString());

        }

    }
```

Output:

```
    Queue [date=Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2018, noOfVehiclesInQueue=10]
    Queue [date=Mon Jan 01 00:10:00 IST 2018, noOfVehiclesInQueue=16]
    Queue [date=Mon Jan 01 01:00:00 IST 2018, noOfVehiclesInQueue=15]
    Queue [date=Mon Jan 01 01:10:00 IST 2018, noOfVehiclesInQueue=19]
```

Comment: I have tested, and the way to get the previous planning is not correct,
    int vehicleallowed=(i<veh.size()-1)?plan.get(i).getNbOfallowedVehicles():plan.get(i-1).getNbOfallowedVehicles();

It does not work if the the plan and the vehicule does not start at the same time

Comment: I have given you the basic logic according to your question and the test case provided. If there are some specific cases, I think you should be able to handle those or ask a separate question with the problem description or atleast update the this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data structure to some thing like the following and then apply the code below.

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> arriving = new TreeMap<>();
    arriving.put(1,12);
    arriving.put(2,10);
    arriving.put(3,5);
    arriving.put(4,10);

    Map<Integer, Integer> planning = new TreeMap<>();
    planning.put(1,2);
    planning.put(2,4);
    planning.put(3,6);

    AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
    int lastPlanning = 0;

    Map<Integer, Integer> queue = new TreeMap<>();

    for (Integer key : arriving.keySet())
    {
        lastPlanning = planning.getOrDefault(key, lastPlanning);
        int diff = arriving.get(key) - lastPlanning;
        queue.put(key, sum.addAndGet(diff));
    }
    System.out.println("queue = " + queue);
```

Using integer key instead of date for illustration purpose.